# Flash acting strangely for some and not others

Tags: xml, flash

I have a flash swf that accesses XML data that is generated "on the fly" by a PHP script. Some users are viewing it with no problems at all and some cannot seem to retrieve the XML data. I cannot determine if there is a common denominator.

has anyone else encountered this problem and have you found a solution/cause?

Thanks,

Comment: By "cannot seem to retrieve the XML data", does that mean that there's an error or that it times out?

Comment: What do the people having problems actually see?  If you can access their machines I'd do a network trace to make sure they're actually receiving the data that's expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ask such a user to access the php directly and send you the XML. If the XML looks ok, it's probably other problems like browser, browser version, flash version and such.